# How to build Sharepoint Forms for Sharepoint 2019

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

We are tasked to develop Forms for Sharepoint 2019 modern pages. Can anyone enlighten if Infopath is supported with Sharepoint 2019 Modern experience? If not, what are the native alternatives? We cannot install 3rd party tools like nintex or other solutions. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath is not supported with SharePoint 2019 modern experience.

You could connect PowerApps with SharePoint 2019 by using gateway.

Reference:

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/support-for-sharepoint-on-premises/

Comment: Please do not spoil your posts by asking for votes. If that is what you are here for, I'd say you're on the wrong platform. It's best to just want to help `:-)`

Comment: Unfortunately, as per the policy, we are not allowed to use any apps that are hosted on a public cloud. Since Powerapps are cloud-only, we can't use them.

Comment: Sorry for that. But per my knowledge, PowerApps is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerApps or SharePoint framework (SPFx)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, we are not allowed to go with Power Apps as we cannot store data in public cloud. Are there any links for creating custom built forms on spfx?

Comment: @Noorul Please check Microsoft Docs: [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)